# Do I need comma in the following example?

Tags: punctuation

> I was at school at the time, slapping a boy who'd called me a nerd(,)
>   when I spotted a drop of blood between my shoes.

Do I need to put a comma there? Why and why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you put the comma there.  Basic English.